# Snowflake - return different (not similar) values between two arrays

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

After looking Snowflake documentation, I found function called `array_intersection(array_1, array_2)` which will return common values between two array, but I need to display array with values which is not present in any one of the array.

**Example 1:**

Let's say I have following two arrays in my table

```
array_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
array_2 = ['a', 'f', 'c', 'g', 'e']
```

My Query:

```
select
  array_intersection(array_1, array_2)
from myTable
```

Current Output:

```
['a', 'c', 'e']
```

But I am expecting output as:

```
['f', 'g']
```

**Example 2:**

Let's say I have following two arrays in my table

```
array_1 = ['u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']
array_2 = ['u', 'v', 'i', 'x', 'k']
```

My Query:

```
select
  array_intersection(array_1, array_2)
from myTable
```

Current Output:

```
['u', 'v', 'x']
```

But I am expecting output as:

```
['w', 'y', 'i', 'k']
```

how can this be done in Snowflake? any suggestions?

Comment: Based on your expecting output statements above, it looks like you want values in the second array that are not in the first array?  I don't think this is what you said in your introduction, though.  Can you clarify the desired result?

Comment: @MikeWalton What I meant was, I want final array which contains all values which is not present in both arrays. Let me know if you still did not get it, I can put example here.

Comment: I assume that the first output should be `[   "b",   "d",   "f",   "g" ]` instead of just `['f', 'g']`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The set operation in this question is what matematicians call a [disjunctive union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).
This is a case where the ARRAY screw maybe isn't handled optimally by the SQL hammer.

One thing is to get an isolated query to work with a barebones case, a totally different thing is to create a maintainable real life query that contains other complexities as well.

JavaScript is ideal for handling set computations, and is perfectly suited for this task:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ARRAY_DISJUNCTIVE_UNION(A1 ARRAY, A2 ARRAY)
RETURNS ARRAY LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT AS
'return [...A1.filter(e => !A2.includes(e)),...A2.filter(e => !A1.includes(e))]';
```

Comment: I like this answer, because after creating a table with a 1 million rows my sql took 18s and Hans took 6s.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim I was first going for an SQL solution, but then I saw yours and figured I couldn't do anything better than that.  But still, the leanest SQL is a monster.  The latest JavaScript really has notational advantage over SQL when it comes to arrays and objects - which shouldn't come as a surprise since it is at the heart of the language.  Thank you for sharing the timing info also.

Comment: I tend to avoid js for perceived speed reasons
create or replace temporary table myTable AS with loops AS (SELECT SEQ8() as seq, 5 + (abs(random())%5) as len from table(generator(rowcount => 1000000))), rowset AS (SELECT row_number()over(order by true) as rn from table (generator(rowcount => 10))), chars AS (select l.seq, l.len, r.rn, CHAR(UNIFORM(65,90, random())) as cha, CHAR(UNIFORM(65,90, random()+1)) as chb from loops l join rowset r on r.rn <= l.len) select array_agg(cha) WITHIN GROUP (order by rn) as a1,array_agg(chb) WITHIN GROUP (order by rn) as a2 from chars group by seq order by 1;

Comment: I also tend to avoid non-SQL constructs for the same reason - and I'm a data warehousing professional and not an app programmer so this comes natural :O.  But I guess in this case the js byte code compiler can turn the compact notation into somewhat efficient code, even including the function call overhead...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using lateral flatten to turn the arrays into result sets, then using SQL set operations you can compare the elements, then turn the result back into an array.

The idea of a CTE (WITH clause) allows you to do all of these in one statement.

```
create or replace table arrays as (select split('1,2,3',',') a, split('4,9,1,3',',') b); //some test data

with a_elements as
(select value from arrays,   
lateral flatten(input => arrays.a) f ) // array to result set
, b_elements as 
(select value from arrays,   
lateral flatten(input => arrays.b) f )
select array_agg(value) // reassemble the array
from (select * from a_elements minus select * from b_elements);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with myTable as (
select array_construct('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e') as a1
    ,array_construct('a', 'f', 'c', 'g', 'e') as a2
)
select a1, a2, array_intersection(a1, a2)
from myTable;
```

shows we are working with the same data.

```
with myTable as (
    SELECT array_construct('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e') as a1
    ,array_construct('a', 'f', 'c', 'g', 'e') as a2
), seq_myTable as (
    SELECT seq8() as seq
    ,t.*
  from myTable t
), expanded_a1 as (
   select a.seq
    ,f.value as val
  from seq_myTable a, 
    lateral flatten(input => a.a1) f
), expanded_a2 as (
   select a.seq
    ,f.value as val
  from seq_myTable a, 
    lateral flatten(input => a.a2) f
)
select coalesce(a.seq,b.seq) as seq, array_agg(coalesce(a.val,b.val)) as vals
from expanded_a1 a
full outer join expanded_a2 b 
    on a.seq = b.seq and a.val = b.val
where (a.seq is null OR b.seq is null)
group by 1;
```

this give the answers, but they are not sorted, for which you need to:

```
with myTable as (
    SELECT array_construct('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e') as a1
    ,array_construct('a', 'f', 'c', 'g', 'e') as a2
), seq_myTable as (
    SELECT seq8() as seq
    ,t.*
  from myTable t
), expanded_a1 as (
   select a.seq
    ,f.value as val
  from seq_myTable a, 
    lateral flatten(input => a.a1) f
), expanded_a2 as (
   select a.seq
    ,f.value as val
  from seq_myTable a, 
    lateral flatten(input => a.a2) f
)
select array_agg(val) WITHIN GROUP ( order by val) as vals 
from (
  select coalesce(a.seq,b.seq) as seq, coalesce(a.val,b.val) as val
  from expanded_a1 a
  full outer join expanded_a2 b 
      on a.seq = b.seq and a.val = b.val
  where (a.seq is null OR b.seq is null)
)
group by seq;
```

gives the output `[    "b",    "d",    "f",    "g"  ]`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you need a sequence like the other answer.  This works pretty cleanly:

```
with myTable as (
select array_construct('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e') as a1
    ,array_construct('a', 'f', 'c', 'g', 'e') as a2
)
SELECT array_agg(coalesce(a1.value,a2.value)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY coalesce(a1.value,a2.value)) as newarray
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM myTable,
  lateral flatten(input => a1) a1
  ) a1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM myTable,
  lateral flatten(input => a2) a2
  ) a2
ON a1.value::varchar = a2.value::varchar
WHERE a1.value IS NULL
   OR a2.value IS NULL
;
```

Comment: fair point, I have just had lots of bad luck with flatten in SF over the years, as things get complex, it has in the past randomly exploded, so I just roll out longer than needed CTE's.

Comment: Ah, but your code will fail if there is more than one row of pairs, which why I included the seq.

Comment: There wasn't a requirement to analyze multiple rows in the question, but I see your point.  However, is there a reason you wouldn't use the SEQ field that is presented automatically when you use FLATTEN?

Comment: to be honest didn't think of that.. but given it's not gap-free, and you are expanding A1 and A2 independently you cannot be sure they expand in the same sequence, thus have no common framework for the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake could achieve the desired effect with usage of SQL and array functions:

- [ARRAY_CAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_cat.html)
- [ARRAY_EXCEPT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_except.html)

Query:

```
SELECT arr1, arr2,
      ARRAY_EXCEPT(arr1, arr2),
      ARRAY_EXCEPT(arr2, arr1),
      ARRAY_CAT(ARRAY_EXCEPT(arr1, arr2),ARRAY_EXCEPT(arr2, arr1)) AS array_xor
FROM mytable;
```

For sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE mytable(arr1 ARRAY, arr2 ARRAY)
AS
SELECT ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'f', 'c', 'g', 'e'] UNION 
SELECT ['u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y'], ['u', 'v', 'i', 'x', 'k'];
```

Output:

[image]

---

Second way to achieve the same result is:

```
SELECT arr1, arr2,
    ARRAY_EXCEPT(ARRAY_DISTINCT(ARRAY_CAT(arr1, arr2)),
                 ARRAY_INTERSECTION(arr1, arr2)) AS array_xor
FROM mytable;
```

More at: [Symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of sets A and B:

```
A ⊕ B = (A \ B) ⋃ (B \ A)

or

A ⊕ B = (A ⋃ B) \ (A ⋂ B)
```